# Can I use an existing Grafana Cloudwatch datasource to build dashboards for a different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard

I have an existing Cloudwatch datasource on Grafana, with ARN as the Auth Provider. Can I use this already existing datasource itself to build dashboards for Cloudwatch metrics hosted in a different AWS account? Or should I create a new datasource for this new AWS account?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to create a new datasource for that new AWS account.